# Migration with "references" clause to a table that have altered primary key

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, rails-migrations

I have never understood why this situation don't work:

I have a model/table with altered primary key:

```
class Pdf < ActiveRecord::Base
    self.table_name = "tbpdf"
    self.primary_key = "nucodcam"
```

And then I write a migration to create another table with references to it:

```
class CreatePdfGraphicYear < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :pdf_graphic_years do |t|
      t.references :pdf
      t.integer :unit_sales
      t.string  ....
```

I think `t.references :pdf` should create a field called "nucodcam" in my new table, but it creates a field called "pdf_id" instead. Why? If I told rails than "tbpdf" primary key is "nucodcam"

[image]

Sure I'm missing something, what?
Thanks you

Comment: Try `t.references :pdf, foreign_key: "nucodcam"`

Comment: I doesn't work: "no implicit conversion of Symbol into Integer/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@402/gems/activerecord-oracle_enhanced-adapter-1.5.5/lib/active_record/conn ection_adapters/oracle_enhanced_schema_statements_ext.rb:77:in `[]'"

Comment: And after this crash creates the table with "pdf_id", I have tried also: `t.references :pdf, column: "nucodcam"` and doesn't work either. However, I think Rails should be smart enough to do it automatic

Comment: If nucodcam column is of type string then try `t.references :pdf, foreign_key: "nucodcam", type: "string"`

Comment: No, nucodcam columns is integer ¿? I wil try wih "type: integer". Thanks